# BroadcastReceiver does not save local variable

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my application I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which looks something like this:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static final String CUSTOM_BROADCAST_1 = "com.cilenco.application1";
    public static final String CUSTOM_BROADCAST_2 = "com.cilenco.application2";

    private boolean lastState = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        boolean cb1 = CUSTOM_BROADCAST_1.equals(action);
        boolean cb2 = CUSTOM_BROADCAST_2.equals(action);

        if(cb1) lastState = true;
        else if(cb2) lastState = false;

        Toast.makeText(context, "" + lastState, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that every time I receive a Broadcast the variable `lastState` is allways false. I'm sure that the `onReceive` method is called correctly. Do you have any ideas why that is? To me it looks like the BroadcastReceiver is reinitialize every time when it receives a Broadcast. Is that right and if yes how can I avoid this problem? My `BroadcastReceiver` is registerd in the manifest like this:

```
<receiver 
    android:name="service.MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.cilenco.application1"/>
        <action android:name="com.cilenco.application2"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BroadcastReceivers are not saved between broadcasts.  Every broadcast will create a new instance of the BroadcastReceiver, at least if registered automatically via the manifest.  You can work around this by making the variable static and sharing it between all instances of the class.  But you can't save instance variables between broadcasts.

Comment: Even static will not help, as is is eminently likely that the process will be terminated in between broadcasts. Static data members are only a cache. Anything that has to survive process termination needs to be written out to disk.

Comment: Thank you for this information also in the comments. So I have to write to the `SharedPreferences` for example? Will except in 10 minutes

Comment: @CommonsWare I've used statics, and rarely to never had problems with it-  especially if the app has other services or Activities running.  The problem with writing to disk is if you actually need the fields to be reset under some circumstances (say at boot) you have a lot of trouble doing so.  So use disk or statics depending on needs of your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you use dynamic BroadcastReceiver(register and unregister via `Context.registerReceiver()` and `Context.unregisterReceiver()`), the receiver can save its member field.
The BroadcastReceiver registered by AndroidManifest.xml cannot. Because it create a new instance every time it receive a Broadcast.