# Is there a way to store instance variable in a BroadcastReceiver - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to implement a counter, that increments its value every time the onReceive method is called in a BroadcastReceiver. However, I see that every broadcast will create a new instance of the BroadcastReceiver, so you can't save instance variables between broadcasts. ([BroadcastReceiver does not save local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557656/broadcastreceiver-does-not-save-local-variable))
Is there a way to store instance variable in a BroadcastReceiver? If not, what are the other options here?

```
class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private var counter = 0
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        SdkLog.d(TAG, "onReceive count: $counter")
        counter++
    }
}
```

The above code is returning count of 0 every time.

Comment: I will define `counter` inside a companion object to make it as a `static` variable so that every instance will use the same `counter` object.

Comment: REF: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects
The most simplest way is to add `companion object { private var counter = 0 }` in the class.

Comment: Further, in the post you linked, it mentioned that it was not safe to save the variable inside a receiver class even in a static variable (i.e., companion object in Kotlin) since the process termination will lead to the variable reset. In case it behaves like this on you scenario, you shall save the variable to local disk (i.e., shared prefs).

Comment: Lifetime of ```BroadcastReceiver``` is up to 15 seconds. I haven't heard this had been changed over past 10 years. It means all your work should be done within this time constraints. It would be better to double check, but I think Android instantiate a new ```BroadcastReceiver``` each time when it call it, that's why you have difficulties to make it stateful. The rest of suggestions like static fields or reference to the Application are hacks, it is better to avoid them and figure out a more superior architecture for your app and this use case in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't.  The entire idea of a BroadcastReceiver is that it's stateless and will be created and started as needed.  If you do need to do this, you need to write your data to persistent storage-  shared preferences, a file, a database, etc.  From there you can read it in when the broadcast is called.

Comment: That makes sense. But since onReceive method runs in the main thread, should we be worried about possible delays in accessing the sharedPref within the onReceive method?

Comment: No, shared preferences are fast.  It's just a file access, it happens in milliseconds if not faster.

Answer (score -1):

you could declare your variables on your Application, then update its value on your broadcastreceiver.

```
class App: Application() 
{
    var counter: Int = 0
}
```

then on you broadcast receiver :

```
override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
    (p0?.applicationContext as App).counter += 1

    Log.i("=====","${ (p0?.applicationContext as App).counter}")
}
```

Comment: This won't work on any broadcast that's defined in the manifest, because the entire application can be killed and restarted.

Comment: it would work on any broadcast that's defined in the manifest as long as application is live

Comment: The entire point of defining it in the manifest is so it works when the app isn't live.  The application would be woken up to notify it.  This solution only works for a small percentage of receivers.  Not to mention, if you're going to do this no reason to involve the Application.  In Java, make a static variable.  In kotlin, make a var outside the class in that file.  Since you're counting on the receiver being the same, it would work the same.  You shouldn't use Application as a dumping ground.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).